# Silent install of AVG 2013 Business updates

Tags: windows, avg

Our company uses AVG 2013 Business Edition in a Windows environment, all Windows 7 Pro. At one of the off-site locations, there is only a Linux server available, and it's on its own network (the site, not the server).

At most of my other sites, I have a Windows workstation setup that is always on, and I have the AVG Admin Console installed for being the updates and program Proxy server for AVG. At the site I need help with, I am having issues with updates.

If I try updating through the AVG program on the users' computers, it always fails (cannot access the AVG site). I can browse the Internet just fine, and download the 105MB .bin updates manually. I can then manually install the .BIN update on each computer, but it requires my intervention on each system for an update.

I cannot select an update on a network drive, AVG seems to require it on a local hard drive. I am thinking of saving one copy to the server, then using the login script to copy the file to the client's local hard drive, then I'd like to run a command to install the update. My question is, **how can I run the update via a command or batch file, without user intervention?**

NOTE: The servers at each site is Debian, not Windows. My organization does not want to spend money on another tech machine, as this site has only 3 clients. It is far out of my way though, so I'd prefer to SSH to the server, download the file to a shared folder, and know that Windows is automatically installing updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a user on Spiceworks pointed out, this is actually possible! [This answer](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/post/4402998) allows me to run a command to have AVG update itself:

> `"C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\AVG2013\avgmfapx.exe" /Appmode=UPDATE /source=folder /pri=2 /path="\\servername\binfile.bin"`

I'm just learning about the other switches that command takes in.